# Https access by ip working but not by url

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I have a server setup in node, everything seems fine in local but in the server is not working well.

```
    server.listen SERVER.secure_port, SERVER.host, ()->
      console.log("SECURE LISTENING " + SERVER.host + ":" + SERVER.secure_port )
    server.listen SERVER.port, SERVER.host, ()->
      console.log("INSECURE LISTENING " + SERVER.host + ":" + SERVER.port )
```

Basically listening in port 80 works perfect and behaves as expected, secure port works only by the ip and not by the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem could be to the DNS not sending the requests or something like that, and in fact it was, if you're using [cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com) you must note that ssl is not supported in free plans. So you can either disable the dns management for that domains or move to a paid plan. Took me 5 hours until I hit it. :( *emphasized text*